# У меня есть приложение с большим функционалом, я хочу запускать через него приложения

Tags: python, exe

Как открыть приложения методом прописания полного пути к файлу **.exe** я знаю. Но я хочу открывать ярлыки созданные к этому **.exe** файлу. Что бы в функцию прописывать только название ярлыка, и он открывался *(я понимаю как это сделать, но как открывать **ярлыки** я не знаю)*.

Comment: Если концептуально, то через словарь, где имя "ярлыка" -> ключ, а путь это значение. Для более развернутого ответа нужен Ваш код и более внятное описание проблематики.

Comment: `def openSource(source):
    way = "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
    open(way + source)

openSource("\Sublime Text")`

Вот условный код, в пути будут храниться все ярлыки. И мне достаточно подставить название чтоб его открыть. Однако, пайтон не рассматривает ярлыки к открытию. Так понятнее?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34737206/how-to-launch-a-windows-shortcut-using-python ?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
import os
 
os.startfile("C:/путь_до_ярлыка.lnk")
```

Еще можно получить путь к exe файлу из ярлыка.

```
# pip install winshell
import winshell

shortcut = winshell.shortcut("C:/путь_до_ярлыка.lnk")
print(shortcut.path)
```